# Session time out in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have an ASP Classic web application in IIS 8 where I have set `Session.Timeout=60`.

It works on the root pages, but it's not working on the admin section pages. The session times out in 20 mins or when redirect to sub directories problem of session out.

I have sub directory named "admin" all related pages kept in admin folder. In admin section I used https on admin pages.

Does any one have solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `global.asa` you may try this:-

```
<script language="VBScript" runat="Server">
    Sub Session_OnStart
        Session.Timeout = 60
    End Sub
</script>
```

or you may try to change it through IIS:-  **Application Properties -> Configuration… -> Options -> Enable session state.**

Comment: But it is not working if we set Session.Timeout for more than 20 mins

Answer (score 1):

You should also look at the application pool and what it's timeout settings are. If the application pool times out in 20 minutes it will kill the session also.

Answer (score 0):

You may programmatically change the session timeout in your sub-folder like this:

```
Session.Timeout = 60;
```

See if it works. Best of luck.